# SDK(NuttX)の関数内でアプリを呼ぶ方法

Tags: spresense

SDK(NuttX)の関数内でアプリを呼ぶ方法はありますでしょうか？

例えば、
１．sdk/apps/examples/helloをコピーして、hello2を作成
２．hello2_main.cにて、

```
int main(int argc, FAR char *argv[])
{
  printf("Hello2, World!!\n");
  /*  ここで、「nsh> hello」と同じような事を実行したい */
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

いくつか方法があって、
(1) アプリケーションの関数を直接呼び出す

```c
#include <nuttx/config.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// helloアプリケーション関数のプロトタイプ宣言
int hello_main(int argc, FAR char *argv[]);

int main(int argc, FAR char *argv[])
{
  printf("Hello2, World!!\n");
  hello_main(0, NULL); // 関数呼び出し
  return 0;
}
```

(2) もしくは、SDKコンフィグレーションで、
systemコマンドを有効にすれば(CONFIG_SYSTEM_SYSTEM=y)、
system()関数を使って"hello"コマンドを呼び出すこともできます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```c
#include <nuttx/config.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, FAR char *argv[])
{
  printf("Hello2, World!!\n");
  system("hello"); // system関数
  return 0;
}
```